# Does the order of classes listed on an item affect the CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know CSS selector with the highest specificity takes precedence (i.e. `.classname` < `#idname`).

I also know that if things are the same specificity, then the last statement called takes precedence:

```
.classname1 { color: red; }
.classname1 { color: blue; } // classname1 color will be blue
```

Does the ordering of HTML classes on a DOM element affect the statement priority?

Comment: It's also called HTML classes, since you define classes in HTML, not CSS.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I have to disagree slightly with Jon and Watson's answers, as...

### Yes, it *Can* (depending on the statement)

Your question is:

> Does the ordering of CSS classes on a DOM element affect the statement priority?

Which does depend on the statement in question.

**HTML Ordering Does Not Typically Matter**

The following *are equivalent* when it comes to a straight call to a class (i.e. `.class1` or `.class2`) or to a combined call (i.e. `.class1.class2` or `.class2.class1`):

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
<div class="class2 class1"></div>
```

**Cases Where Statement Priority for above HTML Can be Affected Based on HTML Order**

The main place where ordering in HTML matters is with the use of *attribute* selectors in your CSS.

[**Example 1 Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvsR/) using the following code seeking to *match* attribute value will NOT have any change in font color, and each `div` will have different properties because of the ordering of the classes:

```
[class="class1"] {
    color: red;
}

[class="class1 class2"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}

[class="class2 class1"] {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[**Example 2 Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvsR/1/) using the following code seeking to *match beginning of* attribute value will NOT have any change in font color for the second `div`, and each `div` will have different properties because of the ordering of the classes:

```
[class^="class1"] {
    color: red;
}

[class^="class1 class2"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}

[class^="class2 class1"] {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[**Example 3 Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvsR/2/) using the following code seeking to *match end of* attribute value will NOT have any change in font color for the first `div`, and each `div` will have different properties because of the ordering of the classes:

```
[class$="class1"] {
    color: red;
}

[class$="class1 class2"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}

[class$="class2 class1"] {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

### A Clarifying Statement about "Priority"

To be clear, in the cases above, what is affected as far as "statement priority" is concerned is really a matter of whether the statement actually *applies* or not to the element. But since the application or not is in a sense, the basic priority, and since the above are cases where such application is actually based on the *ordering of the classes* on the HTML Dom element (rather than the presence or absence of the class), I thought it worth adding this as an answer.

### Possible Valid Use of Class Ordering?

This is a thought occurring to me, based on BoltClock's comment. Consider just two classes being used to style elements based on whatever factors are deemed critical to different styling. These two classes theoretically can replace the use of eleven different individual classes using the combination of attribute selectors (actually, as will be noted later, the possibilities are almost limitless with but a single class, but I'll discuss that in a moment since this post is about ordering of multiple classes). For these two classes we can style elements differently as follows:

**Assuming these HTML Combinations**

```
<div class="class1">Element 1</div>
<div class="class2">Element 2</div>
<div class="class1 class2">Element 3</div>
<div class="class2 class1">Element 4</div>
```

**CSS Possibilities**

```
/* simply has the class */
.class1 {} /* affects elements 1, 3, 4 */
.class2 {} /* affects elements 2-4 */
/* has only a single class */
[class="class1"] {} /* affects element 1 only */
[class="class2"] {} /* affects element 2 only */
/* simply has both classes */
.class1.class2 {} /* affects elements 3-4 */
/* has both classes, but in a particular order */
[class="class1 class2"] {} /* affects element 3 only */
[class="class2 class1"] {} /* affects element 4 only */
/* begins with a class */
[class^="class1"] {} /* affects elements 1 & 3 only */
[class^="class2"] {} /* affects elements 2 & 4 only */
/* ends with a class 
   NOTE: that with only two classes, this is the reverse of the above and is somewhat
   superfluous; however, if a third class is introduced, then the beginning and ending 
   class combinations become more relevant.
*/
[class$="class1"] {} /* affects elements 2 & 4 only */
[class$="class2"] {} /* affects elements 1 & 3 only */
```

If I calculate right, 3 classes could give at least 40 combinations of selector options.

To clarify my note about "limitless" possibilities, given the right logic, a single class can potentially have imbedded in it code combinations that are looked for via the `[attr*=value]` syntax.

Is all this too complex to manage? Possibly. That may depend on the logic of exactly how it is implemented. The point I am trying to bring out is that it is possible with CSS3 to have ordering of classes be significant if one desired it and planned for it, and it might not be *horribly* wrong to be utilizing the power of CSS in that way.

Comment: Of course, it should be noted that if one has to use attribute selectors to style based on the `class` attribute, then something, somewhere, is *horribly* wrong with one's code.

Comment: @BoltClock: not necessarily. I grant that it is (and should be) a rare thing. But, for instance, styling something if it _only_ has `class1` and no other classes on it would be an appropriate use. Also, in thinking about the answer to this question, it had me pondering how class ordering _perhaps_ could be _utilized_ to actually reduce code size of html by applying styling taking ordering into consideration. I think I will work up an edit to explain that idea further.

Comment: @BoltClock It's actually used in Semantic UI's grid system: http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#manual-tweaks

Comment: @cereallarceny: I'm actually curious now if any of the HTML or DOM specs state that order of class names is preserved/guaranteed, because otherwise I can't imagine how something like Semantic UI can rely on it (and is the reason why I posted my original comment - I don't disagree with Scott's sentiment on using it to match elements with exactly one class name).

Comment: Yeah, I just found out that Semantic did this very thing this morning.  I had no clue it was even possible.  In the case of Semantic, they're using a system like such: `<div class="six wide tablet eight wide computer column"></div>`.  Essentially this code is interpreted as `six wide tablet` and `eight wide computer` which is specific to two separate media queries in CSS.  This is computed as follows: `.ui.grid > [class*="eight wide computer"].column { width: 50% !important; }`.

Comment: That you can doesn't mean that you should, even to save some code lines. Depending on class ordering seems like bad medicine. Someone (maybe you!) is going to change their order someday and be hard pressed to figure out what's gone wrong. Even depending on there just be one class seems like a bad idea. There's almost certainly a better way in 99% of cases.

Comment: Even for utility-first markup it has no evidence of forcing specific order, because it is already described with compiled CSS. Utility-first styling makes it basic. Semantically utility classes should be placed after component ones to improve readability, so this order is also a good rule for `class` attribute in markup.

Answer (score 16):

No, it does not. The [relevant part](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) of the W3C standard makes no mention of the order of appearance for classes.

Answer (score 14):

No, it does not, like you said, if two rules have the same specificity, the one that comes later in your CSS will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

No. But if you want to make one of your declaration blocks to has more precedence (w/o many `!important`s) **make its selector more specific**.

For example, for a `div`:

```css
div.classname1 { color: red; } /* classname1 color will be red (for `div`s) */
.classname1 { color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing or a little hard to find in other answers is this:

**What matters is the order in which the browser reads/parses the class names**

#### The class defined *last* will win

```css
.a {
  color: red;
}

.b {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">This text will be blue</div>
<div class="b a">This text will ALSO be blue</div>
```

Example comes from [this source](https://css-tricks.com/the-order-of-css-classes-in-html-doesnt-matter/%5D)

#### May be affected by the order of your imports

Because if this you may need to pay attention to how you import CSS in your files.

For example in my JavaScript based project I have a component that I can pass extra classes to. In order for my own classes to overwrite styles of the classes of the component itself I need to *first* import the component I wish to style (which will import its own styles) and *only then* import my own styles:

```
//import the component first, which will import css
import {SomeComponent} from 'some-library/SomeComponent';
//And THEN our own styles
import './styles.css';

return <SomeComponent className={myClassName} />
```

Like this my buildprocess (Webpack) will put my own classes later in the CSS bundle than the components ones.