# Why there is no ordering in classes?

Tags: html, css

html....

```
<div class="one two">test</div>
<div class="two one">test</div>
```

css....

```
.one.two{
    color: red;
}
.two.one{
    color: blue;
}
```

I was supposing to have the first div color to be red and second div color to be blue, but it's taking lastly specified style rules for the both of the div that is color blue.

So, I wonder why the ordering of the classes are not maintained?

If this was what I was expecting, would it be an advantage or a disadvantage?

Comment: looks like it's by design, it's simply how CSS works.

Comment: Both divs meet both of your css definitions, and css styles can be overwritten in the same css file, hence the last one defined in the css will be set.

Comment: @flauntster but I was supposed not to work .two.one fo class="one two" and at king king I agree with you....

Comment: @C-link css doesn't care about ordering of classes (which answers your question), essentially both div's are assigned the 2 classes "one" and "two".

Comment: Actually, the classes are ordered. It's just that the `.` notation does not respect that order. Try `[class="one two"] {...}` instead

Comment: @Pumbaa80 would it be different, I'll try that...

Comment: ... please do not ever do what @Pumbaa80 is suggesting.  It completely breaks every paradigm of CSS.  There is no ordering because there is none, it's by design.  You have JS libraries that, for instance, add and remove classes at random times.  They don't need to and shouldn't be concerned with the order in which the classes were added.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I tried that and it's still not different....

Comment: @C-link maybe you still keep the rules `.one.two` and `.two.one` which will have higher specificity than the `[class="one two"]`, you can try this `.one.two[class^='one'] { color:red; }` instead. But of course it's just used to test, I think we should not take the order of classes into account.

Comment: @KingKing that's invalid selector you are trying....

Comment: @C-link please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yCPj2/3/)

Comment: ... WTF?  Why are people suggesting absolutely HORRIBLE practices?!?  What @KingKing is suggesting is almost as bad as @Pumba80's suggestion and should _never_ be used.  CSS shouldn't care that the class starts with `one`, as `.foo.one.two` would break the rule!  GAH!!!!

Comment: @zyklus please read my comment **carefully**, the last sentence I said **we should not take the order of classes into account** and right before I said **it's just used to test**.

Comment: @KingKing surprised, how is this working??

Comment: @KingKing - I read that, but it shouldn't even be suggested especially to people that are new.  It's like saying "Well you shouldn't wait until you're 100 feet off the ground to pull your parachute, but just to test..."

Comment: @zyklus Can you back up your opinion on best practices with any sources?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 -- sources: you're breaking _everything_.  You're effectively turning two classes into one, and then preventing those classes from working _with any other classes at all_.  So basically you are absolutely locking the order of two CSS classes to their display.  Anyone with more than 5 minutes of experience should be able to tell you that that is a horrible idea.  Yes, it answers _this specific question_, but the correct answer isn't some horrible hack in how to get it to work, it's that "that's how CSS is designed"

Comment: @zyklus You know what *sources* means, right?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - yeah, someone's opinion on a blog.  I doubt anyone has ever thought to write a post about how to not do something so obviously horrible.

Comment: I got a feeling of getting trolled here. Instead of replying, I'll give an example of a situation where using ordered classes may be useful: `<div class="Peter Griffin"></div><div class="Lois Griffin"></div>`. There is absolutely nothing wrong with that. If you use JS libraries to mess up your class names, then you obviously have the wrong library in this situation.

Comment: You're not being trolled.  Your CSS should work just fine with .griffin.peter, or in your example .peter.griffin.cartoonCharacter.  There is ABSOLUTELY NO REASON to lock the order AND prevent your CSS from running if ANY OTHER CLASS NAME is added.  Both ideas are astoundingly bad

Comment: Order is *not defined* for class names, which means you can either treat them as *not* ordered, which is much easier, or *try* to enforce a certain order and ensure that your code doesn't mess it up (emphasis on *try*). Just keep in mind that you won't be able to enforce this completely. The DOM `className` and `classList` properties are ordered as presented in the markup, but you can't rely on external code honoring this order all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it semantically: A class is just that - some encompassing category to which an element belongs.

If we take the example of a table, some plausible classes might be: "rounded-border" and/or "fixed-width" and/or "blue-background". Suppose a particular table has all of these three classes. If ordering were important, you would require six CSS selectors to target all tables that have these classes instead of just the one.

If the ordering of classes is important in distinguishing between two elements, then create two different classes for them. E.g. one-two and two-one.

Answer (score 1):

Both selectors, `.one.two` and `.two.one`, match both `div` elements here, and the selectors have the same specificity. Thus, by the [CSS cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) rules, the latter declaration wins.

The mutual order of the class selectors is irrelevant by definition: the meaning of a class selectors is defined so that the order does not matter.

Moreover, even if it mattered, the HTML attributes `class="one two"` and `class="two one"` would still be equivalent, due to the way the the `class` attribute has been defined in HTML specifications.

What you should do depends on what you wish to accomplish. The question does not specify that. If you need to make the styling of elements depend on the order in which their classes are written in a selector, there is a flaw in the design of markup and styling.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading above discussion and I agree with what [BoltClock♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) says and others as well.

but I was refering this [Does the order of classes listed on an item affect the CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670631/does-the-order-of-classes-listed-on-an-item-affect-the-css), the use of  `attribute selectors` in CSS where [ScottS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369707/scotts) answered with some
 [demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvsR/) [demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvsR/1/) [demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/mzvsR/2/)

and now I am muddled with whole thing! [BoltClock♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) can you please put some more light on the same?

Comment: `[]` in selectors is a relatively new feature that wasn't meant to be used to _restrict_ CSS, it was meant to expand it.  The intent is to query other attributes with it, or partial class names, etc.  Adding a self-imposed ordering restriction to CSS selectors 1) makes no sense and 2) makes it a pain in the ass for anyone else to work with your code.  The whole idea is offensive.