# Bootstrap 3 - Is it possible to remove padding for col-:first-child and last:child?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason I can't use `:first-child`/`:last-child` on columns in Bootstrap.

Below markup generates three divs with content, all with the same classes.

I'm trying to remove the left-padding from the first-child and the right-padding from the last-child of the .feed-item class:

```
<div class="blog-item-container">
    <?php foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 3) as $item): ?>

    <div class="feed-item col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So the generated markup looks like this:

```
<div class="blog-item-container">
    <div class="feed-item col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>

    <div class="feed-item col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>

    <div class="feed-item col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't enough mark-up there to determine what the first and last children are.

Comment: They're all the same, the php code above generates three divs with the same classes. I want to style the first one and the last one :)

Comment: Do you have a parent container wrapping these 3 columns? This is where you'd need to use first-child/last-child.

Comment: I think the class order matters....if you change the mark-up to `<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 feed-item">` can you affect the padding with `first-child` then?

Comment: @JesseEarley Sorry, added it in the question. Rules on parent container doesn't work for me though..

Comment: @Paulie_D: Why would class order matter?

Comment: Paulie, that did the trick. That's so weird though.. :)

Comment: @BoltClock Because AFAIK, the properties for each class are applied in the order in which they appear in the HTML...so if, say, `.col` had a different padding than `.feed-item` that would be applied after the first class **regardless** of their positions in the cascade. I'd need to check though.

Comment: @Paulie_D: The ordering of class names in the markup should not affect the cascade - or selector matching - in any way. If it does work for the OP, then something else is amiss.

Comment: Yeah...but I had a feeling that I'd seem that somewhere before so perhaps I was wrong. Must be a specificity thing then. :) **Aha - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670631/does-the-order-of-classes-listed-on-an-item-affect-the-css

Answer (score 8):

This css is more simple:

```
.row > div[class^="col-"]:first-child{padding-left:0;}
```

For every first-child of a row with class name starting by `col-`, remove the left padding.

Comment: This would be problematic though in responsive designs with things like `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">..</div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">...</div>`

Answer (score 2):

```
.blog-item-container .col-sm-4:first-child,
.blog-item-container .col-md-4:first-child{
     padding-left: 0;
}

.blog-item-container .col-sm-4:last-child,
.blog-item-container .col-md-4:last-child{
     padding-right: 0;
}
```

Those should work for you. If not, try adding !important (which isn't typically advised but is sometimes necessary when overriding Bootstrap styles) to the end of each style rule.

Comment: what about IE8 compatibility? last-child is only supported in IE9+

Comment: It worked for me. I only tested it on Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this issue myself, as I had to follow design guidelines that only had inner-gutters.

We can use @JesseEarley's approach above for the **first-child** column of the row and use the **last-child** for everything but IE8. To only effect a small amount of performance, we will want to check that the browser is IE8:

```html
<!--[if IE 8]><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="lt-ie10 ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="lt-ie10 ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Now with jQuery, check if **.ie8** exists, and if so, use jQuery's **last** method to remove padding-right from the last column in each row:

```js
jQuery.fn.exists = function () { return this.length > 0; }

// bootstrap last column remove padding-right (IE8)
$(function () {
  if ($('.ie8').exists()) {
    $('.row').each(function () {
      $(this).children().last().css('padding-right', '0');
    });
  }
});
```