# bootstrap row move controls that dont fit in the row to the next line

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, fluid-layout

I use the bootstrap grid layout to render columns dynamically .

Here is the logic that i use

If there are N number of controls columns to be rendered for each row. The col-lg-{} number is decided based on the result (number of controls) /12 .

For example : if there are 6 controls then 12/6 each col attribute will then contain
col-lg-2 ,col-md-2 col-sm-2 etc.

Sample of a bootstrap "row" [***here***](http://www.bootply.com/KXLy65bmS3) .

Now the problem here is if i resize the **window** the controls in row tend to reduce its width and shrink by its width !!. Instead i want the controls that dont fit in the row to move down below ?

Any suggestion as to how to go about this ? Please Let me know if the question is not clear ?.

Comment: If you use more than 12 columns per row, then the extra columns will wrap onto the next line. Sounds like that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

it may be the order of the classes in your divs.  Try this bootply instead:  http://www.bootply.com/j5Qoftk2ny

here's what the html looks like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">One</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Two</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Three</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Four</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Five</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">Six</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Class order in element does not affect class styles apply

Comment: most of the time no, but it can:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15672815/725866.  probably not the culprit here but i can't explain why mine works and his doesnt- maybe because I have a container div?

Comment: It seems your solution is right, but I don't understand what you mean about order of classes. The issue seems to be that OP's columns are all the same # - i.e. col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2.

Comment: Yes, his columns are all the same, lg, sm, and md use exactly the same percentages. Plus he also forgot the container which fixes the math on the row.

Answer (score 0):

Each row renders controls (columns) with different number of controls.

So the first row can have 3 controls and the 2nd row could have 6 controls . These controls are set by the user.

So the challenge here was what should the layout be in the above case .

Current implementation decides based on the browser width , which control stays on the row and what falls down .

I render the div column with the display set to **inline-block** .

> style="display:inline-block"

So now based on the browser width and whether a column could fit in the control will be rendered, if not the column control will be displayed below.

This display property is used without bootstrap changes.