# CSS precedence changes despite identical class sequence

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, font-awesome

I have a react component that lives inside two different apps with two different `webpack` scaffolds.

Inside, I'm using a `FontAwesome` component (`react-fontawesome`) like this:

```
<FontAwesome
  name="chevron-left"
  className="viewtoggle"
  onClick={() => doSomething()}
/>
```

Now, in one of the two apps, `viewtoggle` definitions take precedence over the `FontAwesome` default css `fa fa-chevron-left`, but in the other app it's the opposite, leading to the `viewtoggle` definitions for `font-size` and `line-height` being skipped.

Checking this in chrome debugger, the classes on the `span` have the correct and identical sequence `fa fa-chevron-left viewtoggle`, see screenshots. But still, they have a different vertical order in the debugger, indicating a different precedence. What could be the reason for this?

It's the same effect across 3 browsers I checked, so it's not a browser issue. But what else can cause this difference?

**Update** I was hoping to find a solution that doesn't deal with `FontAwesome` internals (or `!important`).

The good:
[image]

The bad:
[image]

Comment: simple enough to change the selector in the rule to be more specific `.fa.viewtoggle{ ..}`. Pretty standard css troubleshooting

Comment: Yes, or `!important`. I'm interested in the cause because I prefer not to fiddle with the internals of components I'm consuming (or use `!important`).

Comment: The order that the classes are listed in the html is irrelevant. What is important is the order that the CSS files are loaded/defined. Last one wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...they [the applied CSS rules] have a different vertical order in the debugger, indicating a different precedence. What could be the reason for this?

As stated by @Turnip in comments, the files are being loaded or defined in different order. Since the selectors `.fa` and `.viewtoggle` have the same specificity, the last one takes precedence. You can fix this by increasing the specificity of the ruleset you want:

```
.fa.viewtoggle { ... }
```

Note that the sequence of classes in the class string `fa fa-chevron-left viewtoggle` has no effect on specificity of the CSS selectors you are using. However, the order *can* matter when using an attribute selector for the `class` property, like `[class="fa viewtoggle"]` vs `[class="viewtoggle fa"]`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670631/does-the-order-of-classes-listed-on-an-item-affect-the-css) for more details.

Comment: last statement is not entirely true. Order can matter when 2 rules collide

Comment: @charlietfl my rules collide, so does order matter?

Comment: @chazsolo any recommendation on whether it is good practice to use `!important` if I don't want to care about what class name `FontAwesome` is using?

Comment: @bebbi no. Your issue is loading order. Specificity of your rules is the same