# why div's background color is not working as per general css rule?

Tags: html, css

I was doing a experiment... The experiment has two divs and each has same two classes but their position is swapped.
As per general css rule, css effect will only work on the last user defined class.

so here's my code:

```css
.green {
  background: green;
  height: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green red"></div>
<br>
<div class="red green"></div>
```

so as per rule...the in the 1st div the .red class should dominate and in the 2nd div the .green class should dominate...
but when I run the code, Both div are red. where the 1st div should be red and the 2nd div should be green.
Could someone explain?

Comment: The last css rule dominate

Comment: To elaborate on @Piterden's comment: by last, he means the last one declared in the css files, not the last class you added to an element. Order of declaration in `class` attributes doesn't matter.

Comment: Exactly, thanx, @autra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the specification set by W3C, the order of the classes does not affect precedence. If two rules define the same property for the same element, then the last defined rule applies.

In your example, `background:red` comes after `background:green`, so `background:red` takes precedence.

Please refer to [Does the order of classes listed on an item affect the CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670631/does-the-order-of-classes-listed-on-an-item-affect-the-css) for more information.