# Bootstrap Class Name Order Naming Convention

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a current Bootstrap SlideShow. We want to have multi classes for all elements, where every department would get prefix eg :

```
finance carousel-inner, finance carousel-item
marketing carousel-inner, marketing carousel-active
```

The reason for this: every department can have their own CSS-stylings. So finance has green border carousel, marketing has red, purchasing has blue, etc.

Is it best to add department class name Before all class or Afterwards ?
example 
like

```
finance carousel-inner
OR carousel-inner finance
```

- Will Bootstrap reactively differently for each way? In this stack, it says order slightly matters [Does the order of classes listed on an item affect the CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670631/does-the-order-of-classes-listed-on-an-item-affect-the-css)

My question is what is the preferred naming convention, or does it really matter in Bootstrap?

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: why not using native bootstrap 4 classed for borders? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-color

Comment: So class "finance" would become "border border-success" (for example)?

Comment: see these options, finance carousel-inner
OR carousel-inner finance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question, there won't be any difference adding .finnace before or after .caruser-inner as long as they given to same element:

```css
.finance {border: 1px solid green;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner finance">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="carouselExampleControls1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="finance carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls1" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: and Bootstrap native components won't act differently either way or error out? Just wanted to confirm, Thanks !

Comment: I didn't test all of them, so i guess it depends on what properties you want to style... As long as the border is the only property that distinguish between the classes, it will work in any order... Glad to help.

Comment: I'll probably need to know if it matters for all Bootstrap components, does customization order matter? maybe, I should email them directly

Comment: It seems that they separate classes in a way that every class control couple of aspects of the style. For instance if button has pre defined border, adding the 'border' classes will override it in any order... you can email them, you can read the css file, or you can just play with it... Good luck!