# Why putting a class selector before the other make it change, but reverse not?

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<div class="notebox warning accepted">
    <h1>This is some random text.</h1>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.notebox{
border: 4px solid black;
padding: 10px;
margin: 20px;
}
.notebox.accepted{
    border-color: green;
}
.notebox.warning{
    border-color: red;
}
```

If I use it in this order

> class="notebox warning accepted"

warning is dominant, but if I use it in this order:

> class="notebox accepted warning"

Then warning is dominant, which makes sense.
I want to know why the first example doesn't work like the second, and I know that it has to do with the order that they are placed in the css file but I want to know more details about it, why does the order matter in that case?

Comment: The order in which you define the classes in HTML *doesn’t* make any difference, right‽

Comment: Might be because of https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order point 4.

Comment: @deceze If I put it in this order: class="notebox warning accepted" warning is applied and accepted is ignored, which is strange.
If I put it in this order: class="notebox accepted warning" notebox is applied first, then accepted, then warning, which makes sense.

Comment: @Progman so it's purely cascading thing. The browser parses the css file and depending on the order it applies the css. I simply expected it to be dynamic, that's why I was confused.

Comment: You’re saying the same thing twice in different ways. The order of the classes in the HTML doesn’t make any difference, correct!?

Comment: @deceze I expected it to make a difference, I just didn't understand why one worked as it should and the other not. Thank you.

Comment: a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672815/8620333 .. there is a difference in some use cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has cascading and specificity rules. The order and how specifically you target selectors determines which styles will be applied. The actual order of the CSS classes in your HTML doesn't matter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

https://css-tricks.com/the-order-of-css-classes-in-html-doesnt-matter/